# Sample Size Per Design Point - Fractional or Optimal DOE

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, sampling, experiment-design, statistical-power

I have an experiment where there are more factors than budget / sample to test so I am using a D-Optimal design from `AlgDesign` in R. (or maybe a fractional factorial, I dont think it matters). I run this procedure and end up with the design points I will use that allows me to read the main effects and interaction terms I chose. A design point I am defining as factor A - level 1 + factor B - level 3 + factor C - level 1 etc.

Now, the rub. My experiment is regarding customers and direct mail. I need to measure a 'response rate' for each of the design points and ultimately create a model (e.g. logistic regression) to find the "optimal" factor levels and response surface.

How does one then go about determining the sample size for each design point? Use a two proportion power analysis and set that required sample size to each of the design points?